# Is there a  way to use jqGrid advanced search without using jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid

Is there a  way to use jqGrid advanced search without using jqGrid?

I mean, I have an `ul` list and I would like to use this amazing advanced search by jqGrid.

I think I could have a button, which open that advanced search window, and then perform an ajax post. So I could treat the json result using javascript to update my ul.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you show us an example of the ul?  And is it necessary to perform an ajax post?  Or could you do it all server side?

Comment: The ul is not relevant. I would like to use that implementation of advanced search by jqGrid, without using jqGrid.

Comment: By advanced search I mean the option you can see at http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html on searching/complex search section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?  Here's the fiddle easier to see: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xugEN/)

```
$(function(){
$('#search').dialog({width:'400px',buttons:{"Search":function(){$(this).find('input').keyup();}}});
$('#search').find('input').on('keyup',function(){
    console.log('selectValue:' + $('select').val());
    var lis = $('#searchMe').find('li');
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    lis.each(function(){
        console.log(inputVal + '  :  ' + $(this).html()); 
    var match = false;
    switch ($('select').val()){
        case '0':
            if($(this).html()==inputVal)
                match=true;
            break;
        case '1':
            if($(this).html().indexOf(inputVal)>=0)
                match=true;
            break;
        case '2':
            if($(this).html().indexOf(inputVal)==0)
                match=true;
            break;
        case '3':
            if($(this).html().indexOf(inputVal)==$(this).html().length-inputVal.length)
                match=true;     
    }
    if (inputVal.length==0)
        match = true
    if (inputVal.length>$(this).html().length)
        match = false
    if (match)
        $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    else
        $(this).addClass('hidden');   
});

});
});​
```